# Yet Another "Conversion Failed When converting date and/or time from character string" issue

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime

Datetime string is in this format:   `2017-03-07T16:17:59.000+0000`

I have tried over a dozen examples I've found online and here, but all result in the same (or nearly the same) error message.

Some things I have tried:

```
select CONVERT(datetime2, Create_Date, 103), * from dev.dbo.ticket_Data 
where assignee = 'eric king'

Select CONVERT(int, replace([Create_Date],'.0000+0000',''))Resolution_Date, * from dev.dbo.ticket_Data 
where assignee = 'eric king'

select lEFT([Create_Date],LEN([Create_Date] - 9)), Resolution_Date, * from dev.dbo.ticket_Data 
where assignee = 'eric king'


select DateDiff(d, Convert(Create_Date), Convert(Resolution_Date)), * from dev.dbo.ticket_Data 
where assignee = 'eric king'
```

EDIT:
After finding some bad data in the column, the issue was resolve.  It was not tied to the attempts or date format, but the bad data.  I used this and it works as expected now.

```
Select convert(datetime,Left(Replace(Create_Date, 'T', ' '), 19)), * from dev.dbo.ticket_data
```

Comment: did you try doing cast(datetime2, as datetime) first?

Comment: what means "without luck"? what was the result? What is the type of the column Create_Date?

Comment: I've actually found that there was some bad data in the column itself.  so even though the options I was doing could have been working on the normal strings, there was still a blank date value hiding that I missed - once I got rid of that bad data, this line worked:  `Select convert(datetime,Left(Replace(Create_Date, 'T', ' '), 19)), * from dev.dbo.ticket_data `

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
declare @ds varchar(40) = '2017-03-07T16:17:59.000+0000';
--set @ds = '2017-03-07T16:17:59.000'
declare @d datetime2 = '2017-03-07T16:17:59.000';
select @ds, @d 
, convert(datetime2, replace(@ds,'+0000',''));
```

Comment: Nice solution, I will look to implement something like this in the future.

Comment: It is an answer to the stated question.